# How to configure react project to resolve entry files based on the name of the parent folder, instead of defaulting to index.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I have a React project where I'm using `webpack` and `babel` configuration created by [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

The project has a structure similar to this:

```
root
├── components/
│   └── Button/
│       ├── constants/
│       ├── helpers/
│       ├── Button.jsx
│       └── index.js
├── otherFolders/
├── App.js
└── package.json
```

where `index.js` always looks similar to this:

```
export { default } from './Button.jsx
```

I'm than importing these components in other parts of my application with an ordinary import statement:

```
import Button from 'components/Button'
```

I would like to omit the index.js file and make node resolve files that are named the same as their parent folder.

So for the example above it would look like this:

```
root
├── components/
│   └── Button/
│       ├── constants/
│       ├── helpers/
│       └── Button.jsx
├── otherFolders/
├── app.js
└── package.json
```

I believe that this could be solved by creating `webpack` or `babel` plugin.

**So my questions are:**

- Is it necessary to write `webpack` or `babel` plugin to achieve this?

  - If yes, what exactly is responsible for resolving files and would need a custom plugin?
  - If no, what are my other options to achieve what I want?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, why can't you export the `class` or `function` from Button.jsx? `export default class Button extends Component`

Comment: @AaminKhan , I'm exporting the component from `Button.jsx` just as you suggested. But I need to then import it using `import Button from 'components/Button/Button';`, or create the index file as described in question and use `import Button from 'components/Button'`.